# Is there an object in C# that allows for easy management of HTML DOM?

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack, dom-manipulation

If I have a string that contains the html from a page I just got returned from an HTTP Post, how can I turn that into something that will let me easily traverse the DOM?

I figured HtmlDocument object would make sense, but it has no constructor. Are there any types that allow for easy management of HTML DOM?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HtmlDocument is an instance of a document that is already loaded by a WebBrowser control. Thus no ctor.

**[Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)** is by far the best library I have used to this purpose

An example from the codeplex wiki

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

The example shows loading of a file but there are overloads that let you load a string or a stream.